# Syntax error on print-statement in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and was trying out some programs. Got stuck in this one.

```
Python 3.2.5 (default, May 15 2013, 23:06:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> def buildConnectionString(params):    """Build a connection string from a       dictionary of parameters.
Returns string."""
return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams =  {"server":"mpilgrim", 
                 "database":"master", 
                 "uid":"sa", 
                 "pwd":"secret" 
                }
print buildConnectionString(myParams)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Please check the formatting of your code, and correct it. Indentation is important in Python - if it was just a mistake copy/pasting it into SO, then just hit edit below your post and correct it. Please also post the full stack trace and error you received.

Comment: It's worth noting you don't need backslashes for line continuation when you are inside a set of brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print is a function in python 3 so change

```
print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

To:

```
print(buildConnectionString(myParams))
```